# Angularjs (Error: $injector:modulerr Module Error) on concatenating bower components?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs

When i'm concatenating bower_components of angularjs (angular & ui-router) using grunt,

I get a `(Error: $injector:modulerr Module Error)` Complete error here https://goo.gl/0yz6pm

on the built script.

I DO NOT get this error when i'm using the script source directly from the bower_components

Therefore i think it's an issue with concatenation by grunt.

Below is the grunt script,

```
grunt.initConfig({

    concat:{

        options: {
        },
        dist: {
          // the files to concatenate
          src: ['client/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js','client/bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js'],
          // the location of the resulting JS file
          dest: 'client/bower_components/../assets/scripts/coreScript.js',
          nonull: true
        }

    }


  })


  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
  grunt.registerTask('build',['concat']);

}
```

I've also tried using a `seperator:';'` in `options` but to no help.

What can i do to make concatenation work here?

Comment: If I were in your case, I would debug in chrome, check console (there may be errors) and resources to find if all script are loaded. I'm pretty sure it is nothing and you may soon say it is ok (I hope).

Comment: @MacKentoch There is only one built(concatenated) script, which has loaded, this is the complete error https://goo.gl/0yz6pm

Comment: Have you tried concatenating it by hand ?

Answer (score 0):

This setup looks fine, assuming all those script references are correct and you are referencing coreScript.js on your page. The only issue I can see here is your call to `.registerTask`. Observe your implementation

```
grunt.registerTask('build','concat']);
```

However, grunt is expecting a task array

```
grunt.registerTask('build', ['concat']); // close array with [
```

Could it be this task is not successfully running because of this issue? I am also not seeing a call to `readJSON`. Could you be also missing the following in your gruntfile.js declaration?

```
grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    concat: {
        // ...
    }
});
```

Comment: `grunt.registerTask('build', ['concat']);` Ah, this was a typo in the answer, the gruntfile.js has this in proper format. i've also added `pkg` now `pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json')` but it did'nt help :/

Comment: @sal niro, well spotted, I didn't see `grunt.registerTask('build','concat']);` with missing `[`. @Wolfgang, please let us now if it resolves your problem.

Comment: @wolfgang do you have a `package.json` file? Perhaps it's in a folder? This call as is assumes package.json is found on the same directory level as gruntfile.js

Comment: are you just using the command line to run this grunt task? There are no errors returned, and you 100% successfully run this task? Try playing with your `dest` just concat something quick and reference it like `dest: 'js/coreScript.js',`. Is the js for sure getting included in your html?

Comment: @wolfgang have you made any forward progress on this?

Comment: @wolfgang do you have any updated on making progress for this? I am still interested in helping you

Comment: @salniro Appreciate it, but i've moved on to Elixir (comes out of the box with laravel) ever since and this is a much cleaner, simpler alternative